# Python program to convert wildcard mask to netmask

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scripting, python-requests

I need help with writing a python program to achieve this task.
I am trying to convert wildcard mask to netmask.

Input:
192.168.0.1 0.0.0.15

Expected output: 
192.168.0.1 255.255.255.240

Comment: Any help is more thatn appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to invert a number?

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? I think it is just xor operator on the bits. Let me know if I'm correct please.

```html
my inputs: 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.15

expected output: 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.240


ip, wcmask = input.split()
netmask='.'.join([str(255^int(i)) for i in wcmask.split('.')])
return '{} {}'.format(ip, netmask)
```

Answer (score 0):

python2

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> print ipaddress.ip_network(u'192.168.0.1/0.0.0.15', strict=False).netmask
255.255.255.240
```

python3

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> print(ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.1/0.0.0.15', strict=False).netmask)
255.255.255.240
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert wildcard to subnet

```
from cisco_acl import Address

address = Address("192.168.0.1 0.0.0.15")
subnets = address.subnets()
print(subnets)
# ['192.168.0.0 255.255.255.240']
```

Convert non-contiguous wildcard to list of subnets

```
from cisco_acl import Address

address = Address("192.168.0.1 0.0.3.15")
subnets = address.subnets()
print(subnets)
# ['192.168.0.0 255.255.255.240', 
#  '192.168.1.0 255.255.255.240', 
#  '192.168.2.0 255.255.255.240', 
#  '192.168.3.0 255.255.255.240']
```